# How can I set a unique constraint per class instance?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

Assume the user class:

```
class User {
  String name

  hasMany = [books: Book]

}
```

and the book class:

```
class Book {

  String name

  belongsTo = [user: User]

}
```

I want that the name of a book is unique per user. I.e.,  user1 can have books with name: [bookname1, bookname2] but he cannot have two books with the same name: [bookname1, bookname2]

User2 can also have books with name: [bookname1, bookname2] but not two books with the same name.

How can I restrict that the booknames are unique for each user?

Comment: Do you want the `book` related to a `user` to be removed from db when that `user` is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html

```
class Book {

  String name

  belongsTo = [user: User]

  static constraints = {
      name unique: 'user'
  }

}
```

Comment: I agree with your approach, I initially had this but got confused.